# How to get font/glyphs metrics details in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fonts, metrics, glyph

I search a way to get some detailed parameters about font and glyphs through javascript to create a proper WebGL "font" for non-monospaced fonts.

I think what I am seeking for does not exists, but I ask because one never known.

The factual problem is the following: For monospaced fonts, all is easy because space between characters (glyphs) is the same for all. But for most common fonts, this space is variable. With OpenGL, to properly create non-monospaced fonts, I use the FreeType library which provides all what we need to set the proper shift-to-right (Advance width) for each glyph... But in Javascript how to get his data in easy and quick way ?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do at the moment is https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is what I thought. I'll check what is possible to achieve by this way.

Comment: Finally done the trick pretty easily (way more than what I expected). The 'measureText' method returns reliable and precise sizes for each character based on glyph metrics wich allow to construct a table with correct parameters for both monospaced and proportional fonts.

Comment: There's at least one problem with this method, though: no kerning pairs. Char pairs like "AV", "To" and so on gonna look pretty bad.

Comment: Indeed. To be honnest, even with FreeType I never thought this detail. Then, this not perfect, but sufficient for 3D applications where displaying text is not a fundamental key feature. Anyway, if one want to draw text in rules of the art in OpenGL/WebGL in efficient way, one would probably use a way more elaborated and custom technic than the good old fontmap technic.

Comment: Actually, the real best you can do at the moment is something like [opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org/), not a browser API.

Comment: Well, yeah, parsing the font file is always an option, I didn't think that needed to be mentioned.